# Jenkins Git Client Plugin Issue

Tags: jenkins, git, jenkins-plugins

Git Client plugin previously was version was version:3.0.0-rc(beta) which has security vulnerabilities so upgraded to latest version:2.8.6 (latest). But unfortunately all the dependency plugins were still looking for 3.0.0 and believing that 2.8.6 is older version (which was a bug in plugin) are still using older version instead of newer version which caused issue during the upgrade. So tried to revert back but there is not revert back to beta version from 2.8.6 to 3.0.0.

[image]

No Option for revert back to older version: And there is no such version in https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/git-client/ for manual upgrade of Git Client as before one was beta version.

[image]

```
Note this problem I faced in my project. So if someone else is also facing similar issue this might help them to resolve.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solutions:

You have a few choices to resolve the [security issue](https://jenkins.io/security/advisory/2019-09-12/) in git client plugin 3.0.0-rc.

1) Install git plugin 3.12.1 and git client plugin 2.8.5 from the Jenkins update center
2) Upload git plugin 3.12.1 and git client plugin 2.8.6 into your Jenkins server from the "Advanced" tab of the "Manage Plugins" page inside "Manage Jenkins".
3)Install git plugin 4.0.0-beta11 and git client plugin 3.0.0-beta11 from the Jenkins experimental update center.
4)Upload git plugin 4.0.0-beta11 and git client plugin 3.0.0-beta11 into your Jenkins server from the "Advanced" tab of the "Manage Plugins" page inside "Manage Jenkins"

If you choose git plugin 3.12.1, you are choosing the released git plugin and the most stable.

If you choose git plugin 4.0.0-beta11, you are choosing the most recent pre-release git plugin with more bug fixes than are available in git plugin 3.12.1.

Reference: [Git Client Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Client+Plugin#GitClientPlugin-ChangeLog-MovedtoGitHub)

[GitHub Link](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-client-plugin/releases)

[Plugin manual download](https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/)

Related Issue : https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-59336